# Sort ListView Items

Tags: android

I have 2 item types in my listview, Venue and Distance.

```
List<String> ls_Distance;
List<String> ls_Venue;

ls_Distance = new ArrayList<String>();
ls_Venue = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I'm adding string items into both list arrays in a for loop.

(I'm assuming sort function can sort a list of numbers that are in string format e.g. "9","15","20" etc.. and I don't need to covert to int first?)

```
ls_Distance.add(data_Distance);
ls_Venue.add(data_Venue);
```

I would like to sort the items by distance (showing lowest distance first), and maintain the index of the venue.

Note: This sorting can only be done once data is added to array and not before (distance obtained from location updates calculations)

Then I want to set my listview adpater after sorting:

```
ListViewRowCount = ls_Venue.size();
lv.setAdapter(lv_custom_adapter);
```

EDIT:

My code for sorting (not working)

```
    private void sortByDistance() {

    Collections.sort(ls_Distance, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {

            Log.v("TAG", "zzz_compare_lhs: " +lhs);
            Log.v("TAG", "zzz_compare_rhs: " +rhs);

            return lhs.compareTo(rhs);
        }
    });
    //setAdapter();
}
```

Comment: You do, in fact, need to convert it to int first. Are you asking so people do it for you or do you have a code that isn't working?

Comment: I can convert, no problem, I just need the code that sorts, I event tried to sort alphabetically using Venues, that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: (Using TreeMap)

```
 private void consolidateData() {
    if (currentLat != 0.0){

        Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
        for (int i=0;i<stringArr_markerVenue.size();i++){

            data_Distance = Integer.parseInt(stringArr_markerDistance.get(i));
            data_Venue = stringArr_markerVenue.get(i);

            //ls_Distance.add(data_Distance);
            //ls_Venue.add(data_Venue);
            map.put(data_Distance, data_Venue);
        }

        TreeMap<Integer, String> sorted = new TreeMap<>(map);
        Set<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> mappings = sorted.entrySet();

        System.out.println("HashMap after sorting by keys in ascending order ");
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> mapping : mappings){
            System.out.println(mapping.getKey() + " ==> " + mapping.getValue());

            int data_Distance = mapping.getKey();
            String data_Venue = mapping.getValue();

            Log.v("TAG", "zzz_com: " + data_Distance + " ==> " + data_Venue);

            ls_Distance.add(data_Distance+"");
            ls_Venue.add(data_Venue);
        }
        setAdapter();
    }
}
private void setAdapter() {

    ListViewRowCount = ls_Distance.size();
    lv.setAdapter(lv_custom_adapter);
}
```